# Moving rectangles in groups of four in the same direction

Tags: python, pygame

I made some rectangles that all move in the same direction (to the left). When the first rectangle passes a certain amount to the lift i make a new rectangle and this proces has no end.

I would like to make groups of rectangles. So when four rectangles are made then the program has to pause making rectangles but the rectangles which are already there they have to keep moving and after a certain time the program has to make another four rectangles.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from pygame.locals import *

# box-size
bh = 30
bw = 30
# box-position
xb = 1355
yb = 663

### Function to generate different boxes
def random_box():
   box = [GREEN,PINK,BLUE]
   random.shuffle(box)
   return box
while(true):

    w = random_box()
    CB = random.choice(w)
    CB = [CB]

    boxpos = [[xb,yb]]

    for i in range(0,len(boxpos)):

        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF,CB[i], [boxpos[i],(bh,bw)])
        J = random.choice(w)
        CB.append(J)         

     for i in range(0,len(boxpos)):
        boxpos[i][0] = boxpos[i][0] - 10     

     for i in range(0,len(boxpos)):
        if boxpos[i] == [(xb-bw-10),yb]:
            boxpos.append([xb,yb])
```

Comment: Your indentation is off, as your code stands now one would get an Indentation Error.  Could you ensure that your code is indented the same as the code you run? This can be done quickly by copy-pasting into this question, highlight all your code and press `CTRL+K` or the `{}` button

Comment: Where have you defined the colours? It seems you have not initiated the colours.

Answer (score 0):

Steps I would take to get to a place where i can generate boxes 4 at a time involve first adding a `frame_number` variable to your game:

```
#preamble
...
frame_number = 0
while(true):
    frame_number +=1
    ...
    #other stuff
```

With this, you can tell your loop to do something every `n` frames like so:

```
if frame_number % 10 == 0:
    #do a thing that you want done every 10 frames
```

Given your box size of 30 and speed of 10 per frame you will ant to add your 4 boxes every 4*30/10 = 12 frames.  So you will want to put your box generation after a check to ensure we are in a frame that we want to produce a box:

```
if frame_number % 12 == 0:
    for _ in range(4):
        J = random.choice(w)
        CB.append(J)
```